# Tintcolor in custom border of UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibutton, tintcolor

I make a subclass of UIButton for rounded custom border:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:CORNER_RADIUS];
    [[self layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];   
    [[self layer] setBorderWidth:1];
    [[self layer] setBorderColor:self.tintColor.CGColor];
    [self.imageView setTintColor:self.tintColor];
}
```

The issue is when appear a popover the custom border not has the same behavior of the other control with tintColor:

[image]

[image]

How can i handle it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement [`tintColorDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/tintColorDidChange) in your UIButton subclass. iOS changes the tintColor of your button to gray, but borderColor of the layer is still the old blue color. You have to change borderColor yourself, there is no way that iOS knows that the border should be colored like your tint.

```
- (void)tintColorDidChange {
    [super tintColorDidChange];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

After you used `setNeedsDisplay` the system will call `drawRect:`, which should update the layer color.

You could probably use this as well:

```
- (void)tintColorDidChange {
    [super tintColorDidChange];
    [[self layer] setBorderColor:self.tintColor.CGColor];
}
```